# The exception is thrown while using long size string in MeasureString method?

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, graphics

I'm working in WinForms project. In that, i have cell value as string which Size.Width is (288600). I have wrapped that string value based on cell width(350). It does not throws exception when text width is upto (173800) but it throws exception when exceeds the text width 173800. **Please suggest me why this exception is occurred with different text widths.** Here i have provided the string value , method i used and exception details.

 `private const string LongString =
                        "Equals \"1000158.3, 1000530, 1001129.4, 1001543.4, 1001641.5, 1002420, 100278, 100350, 100386, 1005291, 100561.5, 1005705.9, 1005895.8, 100701.9, 10071, 100773, 1008, 10080, 100800, 1008000, 10080000, 1008506.7, 100890, 1009021.5, 1009156.5, 1009192.5, 1009300.5, 1009530, 100980, 101016, 1010296.8, 1010970, 101124, 101124.9, 1011368.7, 1011690, 101250, 1012500, 101269.8, 101340, 101439, 1014403.5, 1015140.6, 1015147.8, 10152, 1015219.8, 1015290, 101530.8, 1015717.5, 1016172.9, 1016706.6, 10170, 101700, 10170000, 1017000000, 101719.8, 1017378.9, 10174.5, 101757.6, 1018554.3, 1019005.2, 102022.2, 102023.1, 102144.6, 102285.9, 102286.8, 1023558.3, 1023570, 102446.1, 1025623.8, 1026, 102600, 10260000, 10269, 1027585.8, 102853.8, 103104, 103118.4, 1032340.5, 1032966, 1033407, 1033587, 1034428.5, 103455, 103458.6, 103467.6, 1034874, 10350, 103500, 1035000, 10350000, 103518, 103558.5, 103693.5, 1037279.7, 1037604.6, 103764.6, 1037664, 10381.5, 103837.5, 1038688.2, 1038855.6, 103887, 1039365, 103950\"";`


`SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(LongString, this.Font, 350, new StringFormat());`

[image]